# Allow specific software versions using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Im currently try to understand Inno Setup and Delphi.

The setup should only allow specific patches depending on the already installed software.

My setup has three patches:

- Patch1: 1.0 - 2.0
- Patch2: 1.0
- Patch3: 1.1

For example my installed software has version 1.7.
Then checkbox for Patch1 should be checked.

For version 1.0 only checkboxes for Patch1 and Patch2 should be checked and the other is unchecked.

I programmed it in the function below.
I used the function from [How to split a string in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23836703/850848#37916394).

My question is how to implement it with ["check parameter"-function like](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) or how to implement it to with shorter function and more reusability.

Thanks!

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Types]
Name: Customized; Description: "Select Installations"; Flags: iscustom
 
[Components]
Name: "Parts"; Description: "Available Patches"; Types: Customized 
Name: "Parts\1"; Description: "Version 1.0 - 2.0"; Types: Customized
Name: "Parts\2"; Description: "Version 1.0 "; Types: Customized
Name: "Parts\3"; Description: "Version 1.1)"; Types: Customized
```

```pascal
[code]

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var Value1: String;
  i, p: Integer;
  Dest: TArrayOfString;
  Separator: String; 
begin
  i := 0;
  Separator := '.'

  // Change Value for testing
  Value1 := '1.9'

  repeat
    SetArrayLength(Dest, i+1);
    p := Pos(Separator,Value1);
    if p > 0 then begin
      Dest[i] := Copy(Value1, 1, p-1);
      Value1 := Copy(Value1, p + Length(Separator), Length(Value1));
      i := i + 1;
    end else begin
      Dest[i] := Value1;
      Value1 := '';
    end;
  until Length(Value1)=0;

  // 1.0 - 2.0
  if (strtoint(Dest[0]) = 1) or (strtoint(Dest[0]) = 2) and (0 <= strtoint(Dest[1])) and (strtoint(Dest[1]) <= 9)  then 
  begin
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[1] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[1] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[2] := False;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[2] := False;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[3] := False;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[3] := False;
  end;

  // 1.0
  if (strtoint(Dest[0]) = 1) and (strtoint(Dest[1]) = 0)  then 
  begin
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[1] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[1] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[2] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[2] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[3] := False;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[3] := False; 
  end;

  // 1.1
  if (strtoint(Dest[0]) = 1) and (1 = strtoint(Dest[1]))  then 
  begin
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[1] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[1] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[2] := False;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[2] := False;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[3] := True;
    WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemEnabled[3] := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TypesCombo_OnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CurPageChanged(1);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange := @TypesCombo_OnChange;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to allow the user to select what to install, avoid complicating the installer with components. Use `Check` parameter:

```
[Files]
Source: "Patch10to20.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: InstallPatch10to20
Source: "Patch10.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: InstallPatch10
Source: "Patch11.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: InstallPatch11
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  InstalledVersion: string;

function InstallPatch10to20: Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    (CompareVersion('1.0', InstalledVersion) <= 0) and
    (CompareVersion(InstalledVersion, '2.0') <= 0);
end;

function InstallPatch10: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (CompareVersion('1.0', InstalledVersion) = 0);
end;

function InstallPatch11: Boolean;
begin
  Result := (CompareVersion('1.1', InstalledVersion) = 0);
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  InstalledVersion := '1.9';
  Result := True;
end;
```

The `CompareVersion` comes from [Compare version strings in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37825650/850848). Or you can use (new) built-in [`ComparePackedVersion` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_comparepackedversion).